# a faster way of implementing the nested loop with gamma function

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, integral

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

[image]

I can find the area for the following polynomial as follows:

```
pn =

   -0.0250    0.0667    0.2500   -0.6000         0
```

First using the integration by Simpson's rule

```
fn=@(x) exp(polyval(pn,x));

area=quad(fn,-10,10);
fprintf('area evaluated by Simpsons rule : %f \n',area)
```

and the result is `area evaluated by Simpsons rule : 11.483072` 
Then with the following code that evaluates the summation in the above formula with gamma function

```
a=pn(1);b=pn(2);c=pn(3);d=pn(4);f=pn(5);
area=0;
result=0;
for n=0:40;
    for m=0:40;
        for p=0:40;
            if(rem(n+p,2)==0)
                result=result+ (b^n * c^m * d^p) / ( factorial(n)*factorial(m)*factorial(p) ) *...
                    gamma( (3*n+2*m+p+1)/4 ) / (-a)^( (3*n+2*m+p+1)/4 );
            end
        end
    end
end

result=result*1/2*exp(f)
```

and this returns 11.4831. More or less the same result with the `quad` function. Now my question is whether or not it is possible for me to get rid of this nested loop as I will construct the cumulative distribution function so that I can get samples from this distribution using the inverse CDF transform. (for constructing the cdf I will use `gammainc` i.e. the incomplete gamma function instead of `gamma`)

I will need to sample from such densities that may have different polynomial coefficients and speed is of concern to me. I can already sample from such densities using Monte Carlo methods but I would like to see whether or not it is possible for me to use exact sampling from the density in order to speed up. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: May I ask what your need is for this awful, unwieldy looking distribution function?

Comment: Note that quad is not actually Simpson's rule, but a variant thereof, using adaptive methods. Plus, these schemes usually use a Richardson extrapolation that makes it more accurate than Simpson's rule.

Comment: @jerad, this is a small part of one of my research projects:)

Comment: @woodchips, yes it uses adaptive recursive Simpson's rule, I just did not want to elaborate that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things one might do. The simplest is to avoid calling factorial. Instead one can use the relation that

```
factorial(n) = gamma(n+1)
```

Since gamma seems to be actually faster than a call to factorial, you can save a bit there. Even better, you can

```
>> timeit(@() factorial(40))
ans =
      4.28681157826087e-05

>> timeit(@() gamma(41))
ans =
      2.06671024634146e-05

>> timeit(@() gammaln(41))
ans =
      2.17632543333333e-05
```

Even better, one can do all 4 calls in a single call to gammaln. For example, think about what this does:

```
gammaln([(3*n+2*m+p+1)/4,n+1,m+1,p+1])*[1 -1 -1 -1]'
```

Note that this call has no problem with overflows either in case your numbers get large enough. And since gammln is vectorized, that one call is fast. It costs little more time to compute 4 values than it does to compute one.

```
>> timeit(@() gammaln([15 20 40 30]))
ans =
      2.73937416896552e-05

>> timeit(@() gammaln(40))
ans =
      2.46521943333333e-05
```

Admittedly, if you use gammaln, you will need a call to exp at the end to recover the final result. You could do it with a single call to gamma however too. Perhaps like this:

```
g = gamma([(3*n+2*m+p+1)/4,n+1,m+1,p+1]);
g = g(1)/(g(2)*g(3)*g(4));
```

Next, you can be more creative in the inner loop on p. Rather than a full loop, coupled with a test to ignore the combinations you don't need, why not just do this?

```
for p=mod(n,2):2:40
```

That statement will select only those values of p that would have been used anyway, so now you can drop the if statement completely.

All of the above will give you what I'll guess is about a 5x speed increase in your loops. But it still has a set of nested loops. With some effort, you might be able to improve that too.

For example, rather than computing all of those factorials (or gamma functions) many times, do it ONCE. This should work:

```
a=pn(1);b=pn(2);c=pn(3);d=pn(4);f=pn(5);
area=0;
result=0;
nlim = 40;
facts = factorial(0:nlim);
gammas = gamma((0:(6*nlim+1))/4);
for n=0:nlim
  for m=0:nlim
    for p=mod(n,2):2:nlim
      result = result + (b.^n * c.^m * d.^p) ...
         .*gammas(3*n+2*m+p+1 + 1) ...
         ./ (facts(n+1).*facts(m+1).*facts(p+1)) ...
         ./ (-a)^( (3*n+2*m+p+1)/4 );
    end
  end
end

result=result*1/2*exp(f)
```

In my test on my machine, I find that your triply nested loops required 4.3 seconds to run. My version above produces the same result, yet required only 0.028418 seconds, a speedup of roughly 150 to 1, despite the triply nested loops.

Answer (score 4):

Well, without even making changes to your code you could install an excellent package from Tom Minka at Microsoft called [lightspeed](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/) which replaces some built-in matlab functions with much faster versions. I know there's a replacement for `gammaln()`.

You'll get nontrivial speed improvements, though I'm not sure how much, and it's straight-forward to install.

Comment: If you try this, please post how much improvement you got. I'd be interested to know. ;) thx